# Word for sudden feeling of tiredness and wanting to sleep

Tags: single-word-requests

A sudden feeling of hunger and wanting to eat may be called a hunger [pang](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pang). Is there a word for a sudden feeling of tiredness and wanting to sleep?

Comment: If it is more than a feeling and you actually fall asleep, no matter where you are, whether sitting or in the standing position, it's "narcolepsy".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcolepsy

Comment: An attack of drowsiness.

Comment: Pang without "hunger" in front could mean anything. I could feel a "pang in my heart" when someone abandons me, or when I experience nostalgia;  a *pang of guilt* if I do something that I shouldn't have; a "pang of disappointment" etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be referring to what is generally called:

A sudden onset of [drowsiness](http://www.healthgrades.com/symptoms/drowsiness): (from www.healthgrades.com)

> - Drowsiness refers to feeling sleepy or tired, or being unable to keep your eyes open. Drowsiness, also called excess sleepiness, can be accompanied by lethargy, weakness, and lack of mental agility. While most people feel drowsy at some point or another, persistent sleepiness or fatigue, especially at inappropriate times, can indicate a sleep disorder or other medical problem.

Comment: "A sudden wave of drowsiness" would probably convey the sense a little better.

Comment: I often find 'onset' in  formal/medical context (see the link for instance) but 'wave' is ok too.

Answer (score 2):

Crash. Used in a sentence: At the end of the long day I went home and crashed on the couch.

Comment: You crash because you are tired. It doesn't indicate a sudden feeling of tiredness.

Comment: I don't think the sense used in your example is the same. The sense in your example is a generic term for "sleep" which is what we mean when we say, "Can I crash at your place?" or "We can't go over this late, his sister is crashing on his couch." However, a "crash" is also what you experience when your energy level suddenly plummets, and you're left struggling to stay awake. Especially used when a stimulant wears off, or after an all-nighter when your second-wind is coming quickly to an end. ex: "I thought I was fine when I drove to campus, but I started crashing hard once lecture started."

Answer (score 1):

A common way to indicate a sudden feeling of tiredness is using the phrasal verb ***set in*** after *tiredness* (or any related term like  *fatigue*, *lethargy* etc.). Also, ***kick in*** can be used.

> **set in** *A desperate tiredness set in after hours of anxious waiting.*
>
> <sup>http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=tiredness</sup>

Example:

> Periods of "driving unconsciousness" usually last only a few seconds while the brain goes on autopilot. Psychologists say that when boredom and fatigue set in, a driver slips in and out of unconscious states. "Brain fade" is the familiar term.
>
> [Popular Mechanics - ‎Vol. 161, No. 8 - ‎Magazine]

Also, ***somnolence***, as a single word, suggests a state of near-sleep or a strong desire for sleep.